# Stored Procedure Run from SMSS is Lightning Fast, ADO.NET takes 20x slower

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

Hopefully someone could shine a little bit of light on this for me. I've been trying to use [Slow in the Application, Fast in the SMSS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#fixexamples) to try and troubleshoot my problem for the last day or so with no avail.

I have a stored procedure that's attempting to retrieve values out of a custom built view :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ARITHABORT ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProcesses]
    @SessionId INT,
    @LastUpdate DATETIME2(7)
AS
    DECLARE @MySessionId INT
    SET @MySessionId = @SessionId

    DECLARE @MyLastUpdate DATETIME2(7)
    SET @MyLastUpdate = @LastUpdate
BEGIN

    SELECT * 
    FROM [GetProcessesView]
    WHERE SessionId = @MySessionId 
      AND (StartTime >= @MyLastUpdate OR 
           LastModified >= @MyLastUpdate OR 
           ProcessStepViewLastModified >= @MyLastUpdate)
END
GO
```

I can run this from SQL Server Management Studio using the same parameters my application provides and this completes in 1-2 seconds. However, when I attempt to run it from my Data Access layer, it takes over 40. The dataset is relatively small (maybe 5 mbs or so).

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
{
    var dataSet = new DataSet("ProcessUpdates");

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetProcesses", connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SessionId", sessionId);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastUpdate", lastUpdate);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter()
    {
        SelectCommand = command
    };

    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
}
```

Here is a list of my view:  Queries in this view in SQL Management Studio are incredibly fast.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

create view [dbo].[GetProcessesView]
as
select P.Id as ProcessViewId, P.[Name], P.StartTime, P.CompletedTime, P.IsFailed, P.UnitId, P.ProcedureId, P.SessionId, P.LastModified, P.AutomationId,
       PS.Id as ProcessStepViewId, PS.[Status], PS.ProcessId, PS.StepNum, PS.Description, PS.LastModified as ProcessStepViewLastModified,
       [U].Id as UnitViewId, [U].Number, [U].[Grouping], [U].EnumValue,
       PR.Id as ProcedureViewId, PR.Title as ProcedureViewTitle, PR.Steps, PR.SystemId as ProcedureViewSystemId, PR.VisionId, PR.[Grouping] as ProcedureViewGrouping,
       A.Id as AutomationViewId, A.Title as AutomationViewTitle, A.UserControl, A.InProgressUserControl, A.SystemId as AutomationViewSystemId,
       SY.Id as SystemViewId, SY.FullName as SystemViewFullName, SY.Acronym as SystemViewAcronym,
       S.Id as SystemTwoViewId, S.FullName as SystemTwoViewFullName, S.Acronym as SystemTwoViewAcronym,
       P.[UID]

from [Process] P
left join [ProcessSteps] PS on P.Id = PS.ProcessId 
left join [Unit] U on P.UnitId = U.Id
left join [Procedure] PR on P.ProcedureId = PR.Id
left join [Automation] A on P.AutomationId = A.Id
left join [PlantSystem] S on  PR.SystemId = S.Id
left join [PlantSystem] SY on  A.SystemId = SY.Id

GO
```

Comment: How fast does it run with SET ARITHABORT OFF on smss? I think default of net client is OFF

Comment: Two things. Don't use AddWithValue. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ But the performance issue has all the classic signs of parameter sniffing. Gail Shaw has a great series on this on her blog. Make you sure you read all three parts. https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/

Comment: @Mono About a second, that change and the setting of parameters to a local variable didn't seem to speed up the queries any

Comment: @SeanLange Is there still a performance gain when you're passing it into a stored procedure?  I assumed since the SP has an input type defined it would throw it out immediately if it couldn't cast.  I'll check out that Shaw link, looks much more palatable then the blog I was chasing down

Comment: The AddWithValue thing is not much of an issue since you are using procedures. It doesn't have to interpret the datatype, but I prefer to be explicit anyway. The performance issue is how parameter are sniffed inside your procedure. Gail's article goes into detail about how it works and why it is normally a good thing and why it can cause problems from time to time.

Comment: @SeanLange I followed a bunch of the recommendations in Gale's blog to no avail.  I then removed all parameters from my stored procedure and I'm still seeing the same behavior.  Invoking the stored procedure from SQL Management Studio takes less then 1 second, yet I'm still seeing 40+ seconds calling a stored procedure with no parameters... Any other ideas?

Comment: Seems we are going to need to dig deeper here. Let's start with the execution plan. You can upload it here. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ It would also be very helpful to see the contents of your procedure. If what you posted it that procedure then the code that makes that view.

Comment: @SeanLange I'll include the View in the question above. That was all of my stored procedure, though to rule out the parameter issue it's currently as simple as :

Select * from [GetProcessesView] where [SessionId] = 34167

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1lizh4Jm